# Expression Tree with List parameters

Tags: c#, list, lambda, tree, expression

I want to create a c# Expression Tree for the following case:

EntityA.Where(x => list.Any(y => y == x.SomeProperty))

I made a few attempts and found a few similar examples online, but nothing exactly like the above.

Any suggestions, references, solutions would be appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the question to include the attempts that you've made, and why they aren't working (error messages, etc)

Comment: @ Luke, I have a bunch of code I tried that I could post, but I think it will complicate the picture. I can point to where I seem to be stack; its the fact that there is a 'list' lambda that gets its input from the outer lambda. I couldn't wrap my mind around how to put it together.

Comment: It is for EF Core?

Comment: Yes, it is for EF Core, but I work on lists that I extracted.

Comment: Ok, why `Any`, `Contains` is more applicable here, or you have simplified question?

Comment: I use 'Any', since I compare the list contents for matches with the Lamda parameter x.SomeProperty. I suppose 'Contains' could work out too. I don't think it simplifies the problem.

Comment: Let me check. I have prepared a tons of such answers. But no one with `Any`, because EF Core works only with `Contains` with local collections, or maybe with very simple `Any`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;

// example data
IQueryable<Foo> source = Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
    .Select(x => new Foo { SomeProperty = x })
    .ToList().AsQueryable();
List<int> list = [ 1, 4 ];

// expression tree construction
var any = typeof(Enumerable)
    .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
    .Single(m => m.IsGenericMethodDefinition
              && m.Name == "Any"
              && m.GetParameters().Length == 2
           ).MakeGenericMethod(typeof(int));
var x = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Foo), "x"); // the type from "source"
var y = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "y"); // the type from "list"
var inner = Expression.Lambda<Func<int, bool>>(
    Expression.Equal(y, Expression.Property(x, "SomeProperty")), y);
Console.WriteLine(inner);
var outer = Expression.Lambda<Func<Foo, bool>>(
    Expression.Call(null, any, Expression.Constant(list), inner), x);
Console.WriteLine(outer);
var query = source.Where(outer);

// show it working
foreach (var item in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.SomeProperty);
}
class Foo
{
    public int SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I run into another issue. In one of the scenarios the EntityA equivalent stores the 'SomeProperty' as a string. I tried Convert but it generates a coercion error.  Any ideas how to handle the convertion from string to int property value?

Comment: @MingoDev any reason you don't want to use a `List<string>` there?

Comment: Yeap, that seems to be an easier modification than I thought. Would be interested to see the conversion though if you have a suggestion.

Comment: You'd need to decide whether you want to parse the strings as integers, Vs format the integers as strings; implement what you want in regular C# as an expression-tree lambda, and then look at the decompiled IL (sharplab.io can help with that)